# py.test multiple tests per fixture

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have the following.

```
@pytest.fixture
def patch_socket(monkeypatch):
    def gethostname():
        return 'web01-east.domain.com'

    monkeypatch.setattr(socket, 'gethostname', gethostname)


def test__get_pod(patch_socket):
    assert __get_pod() == 'east'
```

What is the correct way if I want to test for the following hostnames

1. web01-east.domain.com
2. redis01-master-east.domain.com
3. web01.domain.com

Should I have a new fixture for each or is there a way to pass in a hostname in the test itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this code

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['web01-east.domain.com', 'redis01-master-east.domain.com', 'web01.domain.com'])
def patch_socket(request, monkeypatch):
    def gethostname():
        return request.param
    monkeypatch.setattr(socket, 'gethostname', gethostname)

def test__get_pod(patch_socket):
    assert __get_pod() == 'east'
```

This will create on the fly 3 tests. If you run with `-vv` you will see something like:

```
<FILE>::test__get_pod[web01-east.domain.comm PASSED
<FILE>::test__get_pod[redis01-master-east.domain.com] PASSED
<FILE>::test__get_pod[web01.domain.com PASSED
```